# What is the correct way to use rsync to transfer git reositories

Tags: git, rsync

I have two machines with identical setup. I rsync the home directory between them. I have a "code" directory with all my git repositories.

```
rsync -4aCEhlprstuWyz --stats --delete --info=name1,progress2 --temp-dir=/tmp --include=. -e ssh /home/sindhu/code/ sindhu@192.168.0.103:/home/sindhu/code
```

This seems to not transfer the git repositories correctly, I often get bad git repositories. What is the correct way to transfer git repositories locally using rsync?

Comment: I regularly use `rsync -a --delete` to transfer git repositories, and it it works just fine.  How are your repositories "bad"? What are the error messages?  And have you considered just changing your workflow so that `git push` and `git pull` will do what you want instead of relying on external tools to accomplish approximately the same thing?

Comment: Agreed.  Try using clone and then push/fetch--unless that's unsuitable for some reason that you didn't mention.